# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed - By using different Statement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting the " java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" exception. I googled it, it says it cause when we have several ResultSet pertaining to a same Statement. But in my code I am using different Statement for each ResultSet, but I still see this issue. This is my code. **Frist Code**.

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try {
        pstmt = getPreparedStatement(sql);
        rs = (ResultSet) pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            PreparedStatement pstmt1 = null;
            ResultSet rs1 = null;
            if (condition) {
            } else {
                if (condition) {
                    int index = 0;
                    String newSql = "query";
                    pstmt1 = getPreparedStatement(newSql);
                    rs1 = (ResultSet) pstmt1.executeQuery();
                    if (rs1.next()) {
                    }
                }
            }
            closeAll(pstmt1, rs1);
        }
    } finally {
        closeAll(pstmt, rs);
        closeConnection();
    }
```

This is my base connection class code

```
Connection conn = null;
boolean isfromPool = false;
Vector connectionavailable = new Vector();

/**
 *
 * @return
 * @throws java.sql.SQLException
 */
private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {

        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        //DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB");

        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        if (envContext == null) {
            ApplicationLogger.log("envContext is null. unable to get connection from pool");
            throw new Exception("envContext is null. unable to get connection from pool");
        }
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/CI");
        if (ds == null) {
            ApplicationLogger.log("DataSource is null. unable to get connection from pool");
            throw new Exception("DataSource is null. unable to get connection from pool");
        }

        conn = ds.getConnection();

        if (conn == null) {
            ApplicationLogger.log("connection object is null that taken "
                    + "from connection pool");
        } else {
            if (conn.isClosed()) {
                ApplicationLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection object is closed that taken from pool");
                throw new Exception("Connection object is closed that taken from pool");
            }
            isfromPool = true;
            return conn;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ApplicationLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "unable to get the connection", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        return conn;
    }


}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * @throws java.sql.SQLException
 */
private Statement getStatement() throws SQLException {
    return getConnection().createStatement();
}
public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql) throws SQLException {
    ApplicationLogger.log(Level.ALL, "SQl is : " + sql);
    // return (PreparedStatement) getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    return (PreparedStatement) getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
}

public void closeAll(PreparedStatement pstmt, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
        rs = null;
    }
    if (pstmt != null) {
        pstmt.close();
        pstmt = null;
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        closeConnection();
    }

}
```

Can you also tell me why its working in this code. **Second Code**

```
ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    try {
        pstmt = getPreparedStatement(sql);
        rs = (ResultSet) pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            PreparedStatement pstmt1 = null;
            ResultSet rs1 = null;
            if (onlineTestid != 0) {
                int index = 0;
                String newSql = "query";
                pstmt1 = getPreparedStatement(newSql);
                rs1 = (ResultSet) pstmt1.executeQuery();
                if (rs1.next()) {
                }
            }
            closeAll(pstmt1, rs1);
        }
    } finally {
        closeAll(pstmt, rs);
        closeConnection();
    }
```

This is the closeConnection() method

```
public void closeConnection() throws SQLException {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
        conn = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on which line you are getting the error

Comment: @SpringLearner I am getting error in "while (rs.next())" line.

Comment: does this close the connections?  "closeAll(pstmt1, rs1);"   <-- it is inside the while loop

Comment: @WvdL Yes it does close the connection and it is inside the while loop.

Comment: Why you don't close `pstmt1` and `rs1` in `finally`?

Comment: the connection is shared between the statements, hence an error

Comment: @skozlov I am closing that inside while condition.

Comment: @SergeiRodionov Sorry, how are you saying that?

Comment: But if `pstmt1.executeQuery()` throws an exception, `pstmt1` will not be closed, right?

Comment: @user3635719 are you sure that connection is open?

Comment: @SpringLearner I have updated the code, please see the connection code

Comment: @user3635719 Can you show your getPreparedStatement() code?

Comment: @pens-fan-69 Now I have updated the code. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry for the piecemeal request, but can you also show the closeAll() code?

Comment: @pens-fan-69 Now I have updated the closeAll() code. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @user3635719 check my answer,if you dont understand then I will add more detail

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I originally assumed the statements were sharing a connection when, in fact, they don't appear to be. I have updated to reflect my new understanding.

You are closing the connection in your `closeAll()` method.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    PreparedStatement pstmt1 = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    if (condition) {
    } else {
        if (condition) {
            int index = 0;
            String newSql = "query";
            pstmt1 = getPreparedStatement(newSql);
            rs1 = (ResultSet) pstmt1.executeQuery();
            if (rs1.next()) {
            }
        }
    }
    closeAll(pstmt1, rs1);
}
```

In the second to last line of your `while` loop, you call `closeAll(pstmt1, rs1)`. In the `closeAll()` method, the statement `closeConnection()` closes (I'm assuming though I haven't seen the code) any open connection including the one which is used by the `ResultSet` referenced by `rs`.

Comment: And additionally, he is always creating a new connection, forgetting about all the older ones.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Well, I don't think he's doing that, strictly speaking. Instead, I think he is unnecessarily looking it up repeatedly.

Comment: @pens-fan-69 Can you provide me the solution. I am very new to java development. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I stand corrected. The call to getConnection() does appear to create a new one each time.

Comment: @user3635719 that is beyond the scope of answering your question. However, if you don't want to do major refactoring, I would suggest you create another "close" method that only closes the ResultSet and PreparedStatement. I would also create a factory method that doesn't look up the DataSource each time.

Comment: @pens-fan-69 I have edited the question. Can you tell me why its working  in the code I have provided in the question.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to tell why it is working in the second case @user3635719. Are you sure that there are results (and thus you are entering the loop) in the second case?

Comment: @pens-fan-69 Now I have updated the close all connection, please take a look at and tell why the code I have mentioned working and not the first one.

Comment: @pens-fan-69 As you said, it will close all the connection of resultset including the ResultSet referenced by rs. But why its working in the second code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79137/discussion-between-user3635719-and-pens-fan-69).

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the connection and after that you are trying for result set

```
while (rs.next()) {
            PreparedStatement pstmt1 = null;
            ResultSet rs1 = null;
            if (condition) {
            } else {
                if (condition) {
                    int index = 0;
                    String newSql = "query";
                    pstmt1 = getPreparedStatement(newSql);
                    rs1 = (ResultSet) pstmt1.executeQuery();
                    if (rs1.next()) {
                    }
                }
            }
            closeAll(pstmt1, rs1);// connnection is closed 
        }
```

Lets imagine you have 3 records.
so  `rs.next()` will return you true and control goes inside while loop  `while (rs.next()) {` and now at the end you are closing the connection and now control again goes to  `while (rs.next()) {` but as connection is already closed so you will get error in this line.Try to debug you will get to know the mistake

Comment: Can you tell me why the code is not working for the first one and its working for the second one.

Comment: which is the 1st one and which is the 2nd one?